# Como usar librerias de terceros en c++ con el compilador MinGW-w64 y el IDE vscode en windows

Tags: c++, vscode, cmake, mingw

Buenas soy nuevo en c++ y tenia pensado utilizar librerias de c++ de terceros, la cuestion es que lei por ahi que esas librerias se podrian descargar desde vcpkg y para poder utilizarlos en vscode ocupaba cmake, he leido algunas guias de como hacerlo pero muchas de ellas usan el compilador de windows MSVC y yo quiero hacerlo desde MinGW-w64, las librerias que quiero descargar he implementar son tesseract y Leptonica, mi pregunta seria: alguno sabe como poder hacer funcionar MinGW-w64->cmake->vcpkg->vscode. en windows?.

Comment: ¿Qué estás intentando y qué problemas encuentras? Es importante que menciones esto y sumarás chances de obtener respuesta.